# Why is font-lock-keyword-face highlighting text within double quotes in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp, font-lock

I am trying to set up a major mode in Emacs where I would like to highlight certain keywords.
Using a template from this page: http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_syntax_coloring.html I tried:

```
(setq testing-font-lock-keywords
  `((font-lock-keyword-face)
))

(define-derived-mode testing-mode fundamental-mode
  "testing file mode"
  "Major mode for editing test files"

  (setq font-lock-defaults '(testing-font-lock-keywords))
  (setq mode-name "testing")
)

(provide 'testing-mode)
```

If I use this mode on a simple test file, and type `"hello"` the text `hello` is marked in different color. That is, any text within double quotes is highlighted. Why is this happening?

I think it is related to the variable `font-lock-keyword-face`. But if I type <kbd>C-h v</kbd> and `font-lock-keyword-face` it says:

```
font-lock-keyword-face is a variable defined in `font-lock.el'.
Its value is font-lock-keyword-face
```

**Update**

It seems like it is not related to `font-lock-keyword-face` anyway, since defining `testing-font-lock-keywords` like:

```
(setq test-keywords '("TEST"))
(setq testing-font-lock-keywords
  `((,test-keywords)))
```

gives the same behavior.

Comment: looks like your `testing-font-lock-keywords` definition is broken; check the link you gave again and also `C-h v` `font-lock-defaults` to see the format it expects

Comment: @assem See my updated question. So maybe the behavior is due to `font-lock-defaults`?

Comment: If you are writing new font-lock keywords, why not try my new font-lock debugger [*font-lock-studio*](https://github.com/Lindydancer/font-lock-studio)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is directed by variable `font-lock-syntactic-face-function'

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to turn this effect off?

Comment: I think I found a solution: It seems like you can turn it off with: `(setq font-lock-keywords-only t)`

Comment: Great, this was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

Emacs fontifies two things: 1) Syntactic, this includes comments and strings as declared in the syntax table. 2) Keywords.

Typically, you want the first phase to run, but you might need to update your syntax table to match the syntax of the language.

In addition, font-lock keywords can be written so that they overwrite existing colors, so that you can highlight text inside pre-colored comments and string. See the `OVERRIDE` flag in `font-lock-keywords`.